# Não quero que meu navegador salve as informação do meu site

Tags: navegador-de-internet

Gente vamos ver seu eu consigo explicar.
tipo eu não quero que o navegador salve informação do meu site pois eu mudo as imagens quase todo o dia ai quando você entra no site continua como antes.
dai eu tenho que entrar em todos os computadores limpar os dados de navegação.
tem como fazer no código para que o navegador não salve as informação ?
Grato desde já.

Comment: Como ja foi comentado, isso ai é porque o seu servidor de paginas está mantendo cache dos objetos estáticos (provavelmente apache) desabilite isso, vai ficar mais lento o carregamento de paginas, o ctrl+f5 deveria resolver.